# What is the difference between mat[:3,1:2] and mat[:3,1] when indexing through a numpy matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

For the given matrix below:

```
mat = np.arange(1,26).reshape(5,5)
```

Output:

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
       [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]])
```

What is the difference between mat[:3,1:2] and mat[:3,1]?

Comment: Didn't you test these pieces of code?  Check the display and `shape`?  Or are you asking a `why` question - why's there a difference?

Comment: I did run the code, I wanted to know why in one case I was getting a linear looking array and why in the other case I was getting a one below the other vertically arranged array. Got the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation `array[,]` is to slice your `np.array` in several dimensions, separated by commas

- `1:2` will select index `1` for same inclusive/exclusive reason but will keep that dimension in the result

  ```
  [[ 2]
   [ 7]
   [12]]

  shape is (3, 1)
  ```
- `1` will select the same index `1` BUT will remove that dimension from the result

  ```
  [ 2  7 12]

  shape is (3,)
  ```

---

More complex with `3-d` array

```
>> mat = np.arange(1, 28).reshape((3, 3, 3))  " shape is (3, 3, 3)
[[[ 1  2  3]
  [ 4  5  6]
  [ 7  8  9]]

 [[10 11 12]
  [13 14 15]
  [16 17 18]]

 [[19 20 21]
  [22 23 24]
  [25 26 27]]]


>> mat[:3, 1:2]  # shape is (3, 1, 3)
[[[ 4  5  6]]

 [[13 14 15]]

 [[22 23 24]]]


>> mat[:3, 1]  # shape is (3, 3)
[[ 4  5  6]
 [13 14 15]
 [22 23 24]]
```